# can gcc make test if a defined symbol exists in a source file

Tags: testing, makefile

Is it possible for gcc make to test if a define exists in one of the source files ie.

ifeq (DEFINED_BLAH_BLAH,3)
@echo is equal to 3
else
@echo is not equal to 3
endif

Comment: If you know which source file it is, you can use `gcc -imacros /path/to/source`

Comment: cheers, i want to use it for debugging disassembly output, so i do know which source file it comes from but i cant find -imacros in any if the docs, how would i go about wording it

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at this and to expend on the suggestion from the comment, you could do the following. Not elegant, probably not the best available solution, but it works:

```
echo -ne "#if 1==MYVAL\n0\n#else\n1\n#endif\n" | cpp -P -imacros test.h
```

Or to call it through `gcc` or `g++`:

```
echo -ne "#if 1==MYVAL\n0\n#else\n1\n#endif\n" | \
gcc -Xpreprocessor -P -E -imacros test.h -
```

These would return shell style `0` (true for `MYVAL` defined in `test.h` and being `1`) or `1` on `stdout` which you could test for in `make` / shell.

You may also want to strip all blank lines appending `| grep -v '^$'`.

To elaborate a bit more on the above. I create (echo) as simple file that I run through the preprocessor which check for equality on given macro and results in `0` or `1` being in the output. `-P` for `cpp`, because it's not really a C file and we do not need any of the extra bits in the output. `-imacros` means retain the macros defined in that file, but discard any output generated by processing it.

It should also be noted, if you'd have any conditional definitions needed to consider any defines passed to the compiler, you would need to pass them to this `cpp` run as well.

Also note whether you `test.h` being your header file you know should include the macro defintion. Or `main.c` being a source file including that (and other) headers doesn't really matter / yields the same result (whatver the value was when `cpp` was done with the file read and (pre)processed for `-imacros`.